# Corelle Visions Covered Versa Pot 1.25 L

Tags: equipment, stove

Can the Corelle Visions Covered Versa Pot 1.25 L be used on an induction cooker?

Comment: Simple rule - If a magnet doesn't stick to it, it can't be used on an induction cooktop.

Answer (score 4):

No, Visions cookware is made of glass, which does not conduct electricity.  Induction cookers require conductive cookware.